# Delay Removing a Class in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery delay execution of script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774357/jquery-delay-execution-of-script)

I am writing a small script that, when the page loads, assigns a CSS subclass to three elements. 800ms later, I want it to remove that subclass.

I thought this code might do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {


        $("#rowone.one").addClass("pageLoad");
        $("#rowtwo.three").addClass("pageLoad");
        $("#rowthree.two").addClass("pageLoad");

        .delay(800);    
        $("#rowone.one").removeClass("pageLoad");
        $("#rowtwo.three").removeClass("pageLoad");
        $("#rowthree.two").removeClass("pageLoad");

})
</script>
```

Sadly it doesn't, any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use **[`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)** function:

> Calls a function or executes a code snippet after specified delay.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var $rows = $("#rowone.one, #rowtwo.three, #rowthree.two").addClass("pageLoad");

   setTimeout(function() {
       $rows.removeClass("pageLoad");
   }, 800);
});
```

Answer (score 18):

try this: also I am not sure why no-one above used chained expression might be I missed something

`.delay()` is only designed to work with animations. You'll have to resort to using regular setTimeouts for what you're doing:

hope it fit your need `:)`

**Code**

```
 $("#rowone.one, #rowtwo.three, #rowthree.two").addClass("pageLoad");

 setTimeout(function () {      
         $("#rowone.one, #rowtwo.three, #rowthree.two").removeClass("pageLoad");         
}, 800);
```

Comment: +1 For minifying the code `:)` Also as IDs are unique class names can be removed.

Comment: @Raminson Saweet as bruv! howz life! I was about to dose off, hope you kicking hard! Thanks `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Use `setTimeout` for this.

```
setTimeout(function() {
 $("#rowone.one").removeClass("pageLoad");
 $("#rowtwo.three").removeClass("pageLoad");
 $("#rowthree.two").removeClass("pageLoad");
}, 800);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a function and pass the state, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    doClasses('add');
    setTimeout(function() { doClasses('remove'); }, 800)

    function doClasses(state) {
        $("#rowone.one, #rowtwo.three, #rowthree.two")[state+'Class']("pageLoad");
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hPbT2/1/)

Now it's easy to call, and easier to put in a timeOut, and you're not repeating code.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the: `.one .three . two` class selectors and added the timeout feature.  should work.

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.pageLoad{color:red;}
</style>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>



<body>
<div id="rowone">rowone</div>
<div id="rowtwo">rowtwo</div>
<div id="rowthree">rowthree</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {


        $("#rowone").addClass("pageLoad");
        $("#rowtwo").addClass("pageLoad");
        $("#rowthree").addClass("pageLoad");




})

 function removeC(){
$("#rowone").removeClass("pageLoad");
        $("#rowtwo").removeClass("pageLoad");
        $("#rowthree").removeClass("pageLoad");
}

setInterval(removeC, 5000);


</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I won't downvote since you're new, but the other answers already seem to cover the question. On top of that, you're making assumptions about the OP's HTML.