# How to use ng-class with CSS transitions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have an element set to `display: none; height: 0px` and I want to add classes to it that makes `display: block; height: 200px;` with a CSS transition on the height. The problem is the transition - for it to work, the element has to be `display: block` first before changing the height.

So `$el.addClass("display-block full-height")` doesn't show the transition, as it adds both classes at the same time.

This jQuery does work though:

```
$el.addClass("display-block");
$el.width(); // <-- Forces a browser redraw of the element before proceeding
$el.addClass("full-height");
```

What I'd like to know is how I get this working with AngularJS's ng-class ? It seems like the only way is to add both classes at the same time, which doesn't work as above. Is there a good solution, either a way that forces a redraw in the same way or something else?

I could do a custom directive if that's the only answer, but I'd prefer a better way if possible.

Comment: what about a delay before adding a class like [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815738/delay-removing-a-class-in-jquery)?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is "Class and ngClass animation hooks" from https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations

I edited the given plunker to meet your need  (you still need to implement the height though)

**BUT** animation with display:none and display:block is working here

http://plnkr.co/edit/oH0hh8I1BAPuPz81AqHZ?p=preview