# Jquery .onload with delay

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to install a delay before the .onload() function is used, because I want to show an animation before it get's shown.

current code

```
$("#homemenu").click(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
    $(".cd-index").load("content/home.php")}, 2000);

});
```

Comment: `onload`? It is not clear what you are asking regarding your posted code and your question. What is your expected behaviour compares to the one you get with your posted code?

Comment: i literally asked if i can add an delay to jquery/ajax load command. So that before the pages get loaded it will wait 2 seconds :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found an answer

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#homemenu,#casesmenu, #aboutmenu, #contactmenu ").click(function(){
               $('.cd-index')
               .addClass('cd-main-content2').delay(4500)
                       .queue(function() {
                           $('.cd-index').removeClass("cd-main-content2");
                           $(this).dequeue();
                       });


    });
});
```

[Delay Removing a Class in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815738/delay-removing-a-class-in-jquery)