# $("id").trigger("click") not calling :active selector associated with that element

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a button with id="one" and I have set the :active selector of that button

```
#one{
  background:#00cc00;
}
#one:active{
  background:#00ff00;
}
```

Now I am triggering the above button using some other button but it does not trigger the :active selector

```
 $("#startBtn").on("click", function() {

    $("#one").trigger("click");

  });
```

What do I have to do for triggering :active selector?
I have already bind the click event for a class which contains the button

```
 $(".squares").on("click", function() {

    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    new Audio(audio[mainIndex[id]]).play();

  });
```

So the audio plays with the .trigger event but the :Active selector doe not tigger.

Comment: How about trying `:focus` instead of `:active` -  
`#one:focus{
  background:#00ff00;
}` and `$("#one").trigger('focus');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery events do not trigger CSS pseudo-selectors (focus, hover etc).

If you want to change the color of the other button, you will need to either set the style, or add a class with the style you want:

```
#one{
  background:#00cc00;
}
#one.active{
  background:#00ff00;
}

$("#startBtn").on("click", function() {
    $("#one").addClass("active");
    $("#one").trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: Even if it *did* actually simulate a click (and for the purposes of :active) rather than just executing the event handler, it would be so momentary you wouldn't even get to see the :active state anyways.

Comment: @BoltClock indeed, and this way the change will persist until the class is removed. I'm guessing the requirement is to draw attention to the button, maybe?

Comment: How would I toggle back to the previous color to have a effect of button click? I tried removing the class after adding but it does not work

Comment: @AyushGoyal you use `removeClass` to remove it, but if you're doing it in that same function, what BoltClock says will happen in that it will happen so quickly as to not be discernible. What are you actually trying to achieve here? There may be a better way.

Comment: @Steve I am trying to get attention to button. I have added audio corresponding to the button. So when I trigger the button the sound plays normally. Along with that I want to toggle the background color just like when button would have been pressed manully

Comment: @AyushGoyal in order to get people to click this button? In that case, just have the `addClass` in your `startBtn` click, then remove the class in a click handler for `one`.

Comment: @Steve No steve I dont want people to click the button. Assume we click a button which has active selector that changes its background. The background will change momentarily and then back to original. Now I want this effect triggered by some other button.

Comment: @AyushGoyal I'm not quite sure what you mean, but you could use a timer to remove the class after a second or two.

Comment: @Steve Thanks. I was trying to avoid the use of timer but I think I have to use it anyway.

Comment: @Steve I was trying this but did not work $("#one").addClass("active").delay(500).removeClass("active");

Comment: `delay` only works with animations, check this question out for the use of timeout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774357/jquery-delay-execution-of-script

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind an Event before you trigger the same. Like this:

```
 $("#one").on("click", function() {
     alert("Button click triggered");
 });
 $("#startBtn").on("click", function() {
     $("#one").trigger("click");
 });
```

Comment: Ok. So :active is not a valid psudo css selector of CSS. You should try :focus instead of :active.

Answer (score 0):

`:active` is an interaction state. I would try this using `:focus`

```js
$("#startBtn").on("click", function() {
    $("#one").trigger('focus');
  });
```

```css
#one{
  background:#00cc00;
}
#one:focus{
  background:#00ff00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="startBtn" value="startBtn">
<input type="button" id="one" value="one">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$("#one").on("click", function() {
  console.log("Clicked One");
});
$('#startBtn').mousedown(function() {
  $("#one").addClass('active').trigger("click");
}).mouseup(function() {
  $("#one").removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
#one {
  background: red;
}
#one:active {
  background: #00ff00;
}
.active {
  background: #00ff00 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="startBtn">start</button>
<button id="one">one</button>
```